# When can I define a map from a group presentation to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I'm trying to wrap my head around group presentations and I came up with the question:

When can I define maps out of a presentation?

So, for example, given a presentation $G=\langle S\mid R\rangle$ for some generators $S$ and relations $R$, when can I define a homomorphism $\phi:G\to\mathbb{Z}$?

I'm trying to map generators to generators but I also think relations need to coincide as well so I'm not sure.

Comment: You can always define the homomorphism $G \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Well, yeah, but I was hoping for a little more than that ;)

Answer (score 4):

Let $H$ be any group. Suppose $f:S\to H$ is a function which you can extend to $S\cup S^{-1}$ by letting $f(s^{-1})=f(s)^{-1}$. If for every $r=s_1s_2...s_n\in R$ we have $f(s_1)f(s_2)...f(s_n)=e_H$ (intuitively, all elements of $R$ belong to the "kernel" of $f$) then $f$ can be uniquely extended to a homomorphism $\hat{f}:G\to H$. This is the fundamental theorem of group presentations.